Azure App Service delayed first response for unknown reason
I have developed a client-server application utilizing gRPC for server-side streaming and deployed it to Azure App Services. The server component is a Go application containerized with Envoy proxy to facilitate streaming functionality. The client is an Angular application compiled with grpcwebtext. Local testing confirms proper operation.
However, upon deployment to Azure App Services, a significant delay is observed in receiving the initial response from the server. This behavior is unexpected as subsequent responses within the same stream arrive promptly.
To investigate, a server-side function was modified to send a response every two seconds. While subsequent responses continued to arrive promptly, the initial response still exhibited a 20-second delay.
I see that in application logs and Envoy proxy logs the response is send.
It is important to note that other server-side streaming APIs, such as those retrieving database rows, function as intended and deliver responses to the client with minimal latency.
I would appreciate any insights or suggestions to diagnose and address this initial response delay specifically impacting gRPC server-side streaming functionality.
It just seems like there's a buffer (?) somewhere in the way. So sending multiple stream events following stream close from the server does pass through but connection that send small chunk at the beginning and then stay open for a long time is buffering (?) data before send it... but not sure about that because Envoy and application logs shows that response was send....
The Azure logs on 'server side' show ScStatus: 499 and Result: CallerError when request received for 'long' streaming gRPC function

server cold start?

I don't think so.. There's other request/response just before this problematic API that does pass through successfully
